# Specific profiles for workspace members

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to specify specific profiles for members of a workspace?
If I write a profile into the member `Cargo.toml` I get:

> warning: profiles for the non root package will be ignored, specify profiles at the workspace root:

I also tried to put a specific profile into workspace root's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 3

[profile.release.hal]
# optimizer kills assembly code
opt-level = 1
```

However, it seems to be ignored too, as the applied options in the the verbose output show:

> Running `rustc --crate-name hal src/hal/lib.rs --crate-type lib -C opt-level=3 --emit=dep-info,link [...]

Is there any other way beside avoiding workspaces at all?

Comment: Could this be addressed by change in the source code e.g. adding `#[inline(never)]` instead of changing the opt-level?

Comment: @kennytm: unfortunately not..The optimizer does much more than reallocating code, and Rust has no means to control optimization at function level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is now supported and stabilized since Rust 1.43:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 3

[profile.release.package.hal]
# optimizer kills assembly code
opt-level = 1
```

See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overrides